# What happened in the integral in this question?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm working through an integral problem and it seems that there is a step missing, either in the solution or in my understanding (probably the latter).

The question is: Let $f(x)$ be continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.  Then:

$$\int_{-a}^af(x)dx = \int_0^af(x)dx + \int_0^af(-x)dx$$

Here is what happens:

We begin with basic breaking up of the bounds:

$$\int_{-a}^af(x)dx = \int_0^af(x)dx + \int_{-a}^0f(x)dx$$

We have $u = -x$, $f(x)$ is known to be continuous on the bounds of the intgral, and

$$\int_0^a f(-u)du$$

$$= \int_0^af(-x)dx$$

I'm not clear about the last step.  They substituted $x = -u$, I get that, but there appears to be an extra negative sign in there.  What is the missing step?

So far I've been able to figure out that it involves the substitution: if $x = -u$ then the upper bound of integration becomes $-a$.  The intermediate integral should be:

$$-\int_0^{-a}f(x)dx = \int_{-a}^0f(x)dx$$

Neither of these seem to agree with the last step.

Comment: Just select another alphabet. Nothing more. Or to say $x = u$.

Comment: You keep repeating that they substitute $x=-u$. That's not what they do

Comment: You can call the variable of integration whatever you like, it’s a dummy variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They substituted $x=u$, which admittedly is a pretty dumb thing to do.

Comment: Do you mean they did another substitution at the end?  If so, doesn't that mean that original variable $x$ is actually $-x$?

Comment: They substitute $x=u$. $0$ remains $0$, $a$ remains $a$, $-u$ becomes $-x$, $du$ becomes $dx$. Where is the difficulty?

Comment: I've edited the question to explain a bit better.  The whole question is about breaking an integral apart into two pieces.  My issue is that in the expression, if all they did was re-name $u=x$, then the two variables $x$ are different, are they not?

Comment: What does "the two variables $x$ are different" mean? That is the variable of integration. It is local to that integral

Comment: My answer still addresses the step that you are not understanding, regarding of whatever context this fits in

Comment: The point is: is it clear to you that $\int_0^a f(-u)\,du=\int_0^a f(-x)\,dx$? This is just the most trivial substitution one can imagine.

Comment: Yes, I've got it, thanks